# displaying content only posts commenter

Tags: wordpress, comments

Could we hide our full content in wordpress single page ?

Normally; i want to some text for all users instead of full posts on my single.php
Like;

> If you read full post Please write your opinion :)

If user commented a post i want to display full posts to commenter is that possible or not ?

any help thanks

Simple Single.php

```
<?php get_header();?>

<?php the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my grammer mistakes, Walters

Comment: ¿What's the single page code?

Comment: its regular code for example.
`<?php the_content(); ?>`